# Array of Task in Project VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, multidimensional-array, ms-project

I am trying to store `Tasks` in an Array but all my code (below) stores is the index of that task. How can I store all of the Task features in an array? Thanks.

```
Private Sub Project_Change(ByVal pj As Project)

            Dim tsk As Task
            Dim ol As Outlook.Application
            Dim mail As Outlook.MailItem
            Dim TarefasAtrasadas() As Variant


            'tsk.Flag1 = Activar Aviso Email?
            'tsk.Flag2 = Aviso Email
            i = 0
            For Each tsk In ActiveProject.Tasks
                If tsk.Flag1 = True And tsk.PercentComplete < 100 Then
                    If delayedTsk(tsk) = 1 Then
                        ReDim Preserve TarefasAtrasadas(i)
                        TarefasAtrasadas(i) = tsk
                        i = i + 1
                    End If
                End If
            Next tsk
End sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried it but

```
SET TarefasAtrasadas(i) = tsk
```

might work. If not, use a collection.

Comment: Cool! It worked. Newbie I haven't thought about it. Thanks